# Issue with server changing time almost every night

Tags: ubuntu, time, server, ntp, webmin

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server I'm running with webmin.
I've had a problem the last months where the server almost every night changes time 55 min to 1 h forward.
I've tried to change timezone and such but it still changes back.
According to webmin the hardware clock is running right at CET, but even though I sync it NTP the time still is wrong.

Comment: Do you have any cron jobs running?

Comment: Not anything from the default
I can add that this runs on a VMWare VPS but the other VMs doesn't show any issues with time